# Android Studio compile errors disappear

Tags: compiler-errors, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm new to Android Studio and finally got a large project passing gradle builds.  There's some compile errors that cropped up in the import that I'm working on, but the strangest thing is happening.  When I build or attempt to run the compile errors show up in the messages for a few moments then are replaced by a "successful" gradle message.

Case 1: If I click on errors as soon as they appear the errors will lock:

[image]

Case 2: If I allow the build to run to completion:

[image: Build allowed to run to completion]

If I click on the errors very quickly it seems to lock the errors up there, but I shouldn't have to do that to debug.  If I let the build fully run I can't find the compile errors any longer.  Am I missing something with this interface?  I fear I'm asking the dumbest question ever submitted to SO, but this is driving me up a wall right now.

---

Update

Sorry, I'm on version 0.4.3.  Here's my main build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19

        ndk {
            moduleName "libraw"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call (currently broken for windows)
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':showcaseView:library')
    compile project(':inscription')
    compile project(':treeviewlistandroid')
    compile project(':metaDataExtractor')
    compile project(':oIFileManager')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
//    compile files('libs/jcifs-1.3.17.jar')
    compile files('libs/xmpcore-5.1.2.jar')
}
```

Comment: which version of Android studio are you using ?

Comment: What's happening is it's running the generateSources task right after your compile fails, and this task is removing the errors from your unsuccessful compile. It could be an Android Studio bug, but can you attach your build.gradle file so I can see if there's anything obviously weird in there? Also, attach the Gradle console output.

Comment: The build file looks normal, other than support-v4 being added twice, which isn't causing this problem I don't think. What about the output in your Gradle console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was in the process of converting to gradle and once I had it working I committed and pulled a clean copy to confirm that it worked off the repository. After opening the clean project via gradle I no longer see the disappearing errors. Since it's technically the same setup that was causing the issue, I'm writing this off as an error in the initial import.  The woes of beta software.

Answer (score 0):

For me Android Studio Logcat messages sometimes disappear  (running on Ubuntu)

To bring them back I do next:

1) Close Android Studio (and Emulator(s) if running)
2) In the sdk/platform-tools folder and run command:

```
/wherever_location_is/sdk/platform-tools ./adb kill-server
```

3) Open Android Studio and emulator.

Now Logcat messages appear again.